# When I use Facebook authentication with devise, I couldn't get user's email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I try to make  Facebook authentication with devise.but if I click  Facebook authentication button,I was redirected to usually login form.
below is user.rb code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are: 
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles 
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 

  def has_role?(name) 
    self.roles.where(name: name).length > 0 
  end 

 def self.find_for_oauth(auth) 
    user = User.where(uid: auth.uid, provider: auth.provider).first 
    unless user 
      user = User.create( 
        uid: auth.uid, 
        provider: auth.provider, 
        name: auth.info.name, 
        email: auth.info.email, 
        password: Devise.friendly_token[4, 30]) 
    end 
  end 
end
```

but when I put dummy email address,I could signin with facebook autentication.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are: 
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles 
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 

  def has_role?(name) 
    self.roles.where(name: name).length > 0 
  end 

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth) 
    user = User.where(uid: auth.uid, provider: auth.provider).first 
    unless user 
      user = User.create( 
        uid: auth.uid, 
        provider: auth.provider, 
        name: auth.info.name, 
        email:    User.dummy_email(auth), 
        password: Devise.friendly_token[4, 30]) 
    end 
    user 
  end 

 private 
  def self.dummy_email(auth) 
    "#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}@example.com" 
  end 
end
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What does `puts auth.info.email` show if you trying insert this line of code inside  self.find_for_oauth? could you also try User.create!() instead of  User.create()? Was just thinking that maybe it failed some validation or something.

Answer (score 0):

It's validation issue, because facebook doesn't provide email address if user don't want to share email publicly.

So you need to add a checking for blank email. If email is blank then you can create a email with his first name + last name + some ramdom uniq number.

Then you ask user to enter his valid email.